# SWIG Generating C++ Python3 wrapper in Windows causes assertion MSVC 2017

Tags: python, c++, swig

Using SWIG to generate a wrapper around a C++ class is causing a strange assertion at run-time:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Python37\python37_d.dll
File: c:\_work\4\s\objects\typeobject.c
Line: 3634

Expression: PyTuple_Check(args)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)
```

If ignore is clicked on the dialogue that pops up, everything seems to work fine.

I've created an example program to try replicate the problem and have experienced the same issue:

main.cpp

```
#include "testwrapper.h"

#pragma push_macro("slots")
#undef slots
#include "Python.h"
#pragma pop_macro("slots")

#include "SwigModules/generated/swig_runtime.h"

PyObject * ConvertToWrapper(SwigInterface * instance)
{
    swig_type_info * pTypeInfo = SWIG_TypeQuery("SwigInterface *");
    PyObject* obj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(instance, pTypeInfo, 0); <- issue occurs here
    return obj;
}

TestWrapper * wrapper = new TestWrapper();

void TestSwig()
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("import test_module");
  ConvertToWrapper(wrapper);
  Py_Finalize();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  TestSwig();
  return 0;
}
```

testwrapper.h

```
#pragma once
#include "swiginterface.h"

class TestWrapper : public  SwigInterface
{
public:
  TestWrapper(){}
  virtual ~TestWrapper(){}
  virtual void Test();
};
```

swiginterface.h

```
#pragma once

class SwigInterface
{
public:
  virtual ~SwigInterface(){}
  virtual void Test() = 0;
};
```

test_module.i (swig interface file)

```
%module test_module

%{
#include "../swiginterface.h"
%}

%include "../SwigInterface.h"

%inline %{
  SwigInterface * test;
%}
```

setup_function (python)

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name="test_module",
      py_modules=['test_module'],
      ext_modules=[Extension("_test_module",
                     ["test_module.i"],
                     extra_compile_args=["-DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=test_module"],
                     swig_opts=["-c++", "-py3"],
                  )])
```

Function in swig_runtime.h where issue occurs:

```
SWIGRUNTIME PyObject* 
SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance(SwigPyClientData *data, PyObject *swig_this)
{
#if (PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x02020000)
  PyObject *inst = 0;
  PyObject *newraw = data->newraw;
  if (newraw) {
    inst = PyObject_Call(newraw, data->newargs, NULL);
    if (inst) {
#if !defined(SWIG_PYTHON_SLOW_GETSET_THIS)
      PyObject **dictptr = _PyObject_GetDictPtr(inst);
      if (dictptr != NULL) {
    PyObject *dict = *dictptr;
    if (dict == NULL) {
      dict = PyDict_New();
      *dictptr = dict;
      PyDict_SetItem(dict, SWIG_This(), swig_this);
    }
      }
#else
      PyObject *key = SWIG_This();
      PyObject_SetAttr(inst, key, swig_this);
#endif
    }
  } else {
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
    inst = ((PyTypeObject*) data->newargs)->tp_new((PyTypeObject*) data->newargs, Py_None, Py_None); //<----- HERE
    if (inst) {
      PyObject_SetAttr(inst, SWIG_This(), swig_this);
      Py_TYPE(inst)->tp_flags &= ~Py_TPFLAGS_VALID_VERSION_TAG;
    }
#else
    PyObject *dict = PyDict_New();
    if (dict) {
      PyDict_SetItem(dict, SWIG_This(), swig_this);
      inst = PyInstance_NewRaw(data->newargs, dict);
      Py_DECREF(dict);
    }
#endif
  }
  return inst;
```

I've tried this with multiple versions of SWIG and all result the same. It loads the module no problem, both into the C++ code and into an external python interpreter. How do I go about debugging / fixing this issue?

Comment: Debug the call that fails? I suppose there is some Python somewhere? Where is it?

Comment: No python at this point, it's for passing a pointer into python so it can be used in the embedded interpreter. The code works on Linux / Mac and did using previous version of windows.

Comment: Both the instance and pTypeInfo pointers are ok. The last argument is for flags, which should be set to 0

Comment: On Windows, I `#undef _DEBUG` before including `Python.h` and explicitly link to the release version of Python37. Your errors may be related to debug/release linking of python libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I needed to downgrade from Python3.7 to Python3.6

Answer (score 0):

Or upgrade to SWIG 4.0, which has a [fix](https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/1321).